# Close component on outside click- reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am building something like this in reactJs.

```
<div className={'stories-outer'}> //div #1
    <div>  //div #2
        ...
    <div/>
</div>
```

I want to close the component on clicking anywhere ouside `div #2`.

I tried it using `onBlur` property like this:

```
<div className={'stories-outer'} onBlur={()=>showComponent(false)} tabIndex='0'> //div #1
    <div>  //div #2
        ...
    <div/>
</div>
```

But was not working.

I also tried using `onClick` like this:

```
<div className={'stories-outer'} onClick={()=>showComponent(false)}> //div #1
    <div>  //div #2
        ...
    <div/>
</div>
```

But the component was closed on clicking inside `div #2` also, which should not happen. Please share a solution. Thank you :)

Comment: check with `event.target` with a `ref` then close it otherwise let it continue showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you seek the [event.stopPropagation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute-in-javascript/) method.

Example:

```
<div className={'stories-outer'} onClick={()=>showComponent(false)}> //div #1
    <div onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}>  //div #2
        ...
    <div/>
</div>
```